# Does Alexander's horned sphere bound a ball?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I am bit puzzled by two facts from two Hatcher's books, they seem contradictory to me:

1) In Notes on 3-Manifolds [3MF], he proves that smooth embeddings  $S^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ bound a ball. Before the proof, he notes, that this doesn't hold for merely topological embeddings since the Alexander horned sphere is a counterexample. Yet

2) in Algebraic Topology [AT], he proves that the horned sphere IS a boundary of embedded ball.

What am I missing? Am I reading something incorrectly?

[[AT](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf)] Example 2B.2 on page 170,

[[3MF](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/3M/3Mfds.pdf)] Theorem 1.1 on page 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you embed Alexander's horned sphere into $S^3$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^3$. The complement of this horned sphere in $S^3$ is now made of two parts, one part that is ball-shaped and one part that is not ball-shaped. If you puncture $S^3$ in the not-ball-shaped region, you get the usual embedding of the horned sphere into $\mathbb{R}^3$. But if you puncture $S^3$ in the ball-shaped region, you get a different embedding into $\mathbb{R}^3$ where the horns are on the *inside*. This embedding is the counterexample mentioned in [3MF].

Comment: ah, thanks! I've expected the answer to be easy, but not this easy :) Just a little follow-up: If we would add to this sphere with horns inside an additional pair of horns outside, would we get an embedding such that no region of the complement is simply connected?

Comment: That is correct.