# Do homeomorphisms of disks in a sphere extend?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

Suppose $D_1$ and $D_2$ are two n-dimensional closed disks (topologically embedded) in the sphere $S^n$ ($n>=1$). Is there a homeomorphism $f:S^n \rightarrow S^n$ such that $f(D_1)=D_2$? Maybe I should ask whether all the embeddings of $D^n$ in $S^n$ are ambient isotopic?

When $n=1$, a disk is just a closed connected arc on the circle. There is an obvious construction using stretching and rotation. When $n=2$, Schoenflies theorem implies the result trivially. I am also interested in the smooth category.

Comment: Do you know about wild spheres?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299023/does-alexanders-horned-sphere-bound-a-ball) for a counterexample when $n=3$.